# With enableLazyInitialization = true, I am not able to save the Entity Object with CascadeType None

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, lazy-loading, cascade

I am using hibernate.enhancer.enableLazyInitialization = true in my Spring boot application.

hibernate version - 5.6.15

I have an entity Sample.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sample")
public class Sample {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "sample_config_id")
    private SampleConfig sampleConfig;

    @Column(name = "satus", length = 10)
    private String status;

}
```

And I am trying to do

```
Sample sample = sampleRepository.findById(1L);

sample.setStatus("ACTIVE");

sampleRepository.save(sample) ;
```

but this is throwing error

`object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.xxx.xxx.xxx.Sample.sampleConfig`

It is working as expected if I remove fetch type Lazy in @ManyToOne. But my requirement is that I want to fetch the entity lazily but while saving, I don't want to Cascade on any operation.

If I do CascadeType.ALL it is updating the sample_config table also with null fields.

If I do enableLazyInitialization = false and CascadeType.ALL it is not updating the sample_config but saving the sample ( This is my expected behaviour but I require lazy fetch )